# Required changes for Ionic 2 call,sms and mailto functionalities in config.xml file?

Tags: android, ios, xml, angular, ionic2

I have the following codes to invoke the android mobile sms and phone call activity

To send an SMS

```
<ion-item-options side="left">      
        <a  ion-button [href]="sanitize('sms:'+ user.mobile_no)"><ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon> Text</a>
        <a ion-button href="tel:{{user.mobile_no}}"><ion-icon></ion-icon> Call</a>
</ion-item-options>
```

Sanitize function implemented properly there is no error exits.

Another Approach

```
<button ion-button (click)="callMe(user)">{{user.mobile_no}}</button>
```

Component Code

```
public callMe(user) {
    document.location.href = 'tel:'+user.mobile_no;
}
```

**All are not working.**

I didn't do any changes on config.xml file. Is I have to update anything else to send an email, call or sms?

My Config XML look like this

```
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*"/>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried developing in windows and build is generating in Ubuntu. Hence the plugin installation is not proper.

So I executed the following commands to add the plugin again then it works fine.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova prepare
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove all code with word "allow-*" and just add some below code:

```
   <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
```

and run command : "ionic build android ". You can reference [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) to know more detail.

Cheer !